# Is limit of function a limit point of image of function?

Tags: real-analysis, functions

Let $S\subset \mathbb{R}^n$. A point $x$ is a limit point of $S$ if every ball centered at $x$  intersects $A$ at some point other than $x$.

Now suppose that $f: S\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$ and $\lim_{x \to c} f(x)=L$.

Is $L$ always a limit point of $f(S)$? I think that it is, or else $f$ is eventually constant at $L$, but this is just my intuition and I can't prove it.

I'd appreciate knowing the answer and seeing why it's true.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume $L$ is *not* a limit point of $f(S)$.

There exists $\epsilon > 0$ with the property that $0 < |y-L| < \epsilon$ implies $y \notin f(S)$. ($L$ itself may or may not be an element of $f(S)$ at this stage).

Since $f(x) \to L$ as $x \to c$, there exists $\delta > 0$ with the property that $x \in S$ and $0 < |x-c| < \delta$ implies $|f(x) - L| < \epsilon$.

Suppose $x \in S$ and $0 < |x-c| < \delta$. If $f(x) \not= L$, it would follows that $f(x) \notin f(S)$. Thus $0 < |x-c| < \delta \implies f(x) = L$.

Thus $L \in f(S)$, meaning $L$ is an isolated point of $f(S)$, and $f$ is indeed constant in a neighborhood of $c$.